# Polychromatic Error: Wrong Qt Library Version (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, mouse, wayland, qt

I got a new Razer mouse, and I'm trying to use Polychromatic to alter colors/DPI. I installed openrazer and Polychromatic as specified on their websites for Ubuntu 22.04, but when I run `polychromatic-controller` in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (5.15.3) with this library (5.15.2)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm not sure what to do here, is my Ubuntu's Qt library outdated? Or is the Polychromatic Qt library outdated and I need to download an older version? I assume the warning about wayland is may have something to do with it, but I'm not sure about the environment variables it wants me to set. What do those do, and are there any downsides?

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't figured out a solution for polychromatic yet, but I did find an error I had with openrazer: I needed to disable secure boot. After disabling secure boot, I still received the same error with polychromatic. However, I did also install razergenie, and it started working after the secure boot fix.